# PHP calculate difference between two dates WITHOUT year

Tags: php, date, datetime

I generally use this method to calculate difference between two dates:

```
$datediff = strtotime($enddate) - strtotime($startdate);        
$totalDays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

But now I got a problem. Now I should not consider the year in the calculation. Which means for example the difference between two dates January 2 2014 and January 6 2015 should give me result as 4 days.

For that I changed the date format to `m-d`, and used the below method:

```
$startdate = date('m-d',strtotime($startdate));
$enddate = date('m-d',strtotime($enddate));
$datediff = $enddate - $startdate;
$totalDays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

But I get the result as 0. Can anyone help me? What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Have you considered leap years?

Comment: so many bad solutions :( use the php date time object only pass in m-d part of date and use the date diff function there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this :

```
$startdate = 'January 1 2014';
$enddate =  'February 6 2015';
$startdate = date('d-m-1970',strtotime($startdate));
$enddate = date('d-m-1970',strtotime($enddate));
$datediff = strtotime($enddate) - strtotime($startdate);
$totalDays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
echo $totalDays;
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the year with 1970 and do the calculations against that.

```
$date1 = '2014-01-17 04:05:54';
$date2 = '2013-01-12 02:07:54';

$date1 = preg_replace('/([\d]{4})/', '1970', $date1);
$date2 = preg_replace('/([\d]{4})/', '1970', $date2);

$timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);

$date_diff = gmdate('d H:i:s', abs($timestamp2-$timestamp1));

var_dump($date_diff);
```

Comment: I would use 1972 so that we can test against leap years too :)

Answer (score 3):

here is the php DateTime solution

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2015-01-02');
$date2 = new DateTime('2014-01-06');

switch (true) {
    case ($date1 < $date2) :
        $date2->setDate($date1->format('Y'), $date2->format('m'), $date2->format('d'));
        break;

    case ($date2 < $date1) :
        $date1->setDate($date2->format('Y'), $date1->format('m'), $date1->format('d'));
        break;
}

$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); // +4 days
```

have fun!

Or just cut off the year and leave away the switch part.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the "m-d" part of your date and append any year onto the end of it, e.g. "-2014".  The `datediff()` will then give you the required answer.